# Chrome security tab missing "View Certificate" Button

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, certificate

So a while back Chrome removed the URL bar link to the page certificate.  That's fine.  I guess.  However, I have a self-signed certificate I'm using, and I used Chrome to go to a URL using it.  I added an exception for the certificate/page/etc.  However, I wanted to view the certificate, and the (new) button that's supposed to be in the Security tab is not there:

[Note: This screenshot makes it look like I'm looking at a `data:` URL, but the real URL was `https://127.0.0.1/:61616/`, which elicited a "This page isn’t working" message. (Submessage: "127.0.0.1 sent an invalid response." "ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE")]

[image: Security tab missing cert button]

Compare a normal, valid page:

[image: Security tab properly has cert button]

It may be worth noting that *my* url is not a proper web page; it points to an ActiveMQ server.  Still, now I've added an exception for a certificate I can no longer view, which seems erroneous, as well as frustrating.

Comment: Any luck on solving this one?

Comment: @Velox Sorry, nope.  I mostly use Firefox, though, so I haven't really thought about it much since I asked the question.